# Positioning Layers and text gradients with css

Tags: css, z-index, gradient

I'm a CSS newbie trying to get some text gradients going on. I tried this code [here](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/02/04/css-web-20-glossy-text/) but it didn't work for me, most likely because the h1 object is nested within a #header div. I imagine there's something to do with layers that I don't know about. Either I get a gradent block that is in front of everything or it's not appearing at all.

In this particular instance this code makes a big gradient bar appear in front of everything:

```
    #header {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    background:#080E73 url(../images/header-background.png) repeat-x left 0px;
    width:100%;
    max-height: 175px;
    color: #080E73;
}
#header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
}
#header h1 span {
  background:url(../images/headline-text.png) repeat-x;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is the HTML (I'm using ruby on rails hence the notation)

```
     <div id="header">
  <% unless flash[:notice].blank? %>
    <div id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
  <% end %>
        <%= image_tag ("header-image.png") %>
        <h1><span></span>Headline</h1> <strong>Byline</strong>
... #navbar html...
</div>
```

I tried playing with z-index but I couldn't come up with any good results. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Nesting in `div` doesn't matter as long as `h1` has `position:relative` which should set it as container for the `span`.

Comment: Hm...Maybe I have some odd selector floating around that makes it not work.

Comment: I think the syntax highlighting identifies the problem all by itself. You have a syntax error, `font: font: `. See that huge red code chunk after that? The correct parsing resumes only at `background:url`. I.e. the style for `#header h1 span` actually gets applied to `#header h1`.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for catching that there. Although it still doesn't work...

Comment: Okay, but we've still got a problem there, a chunk of code is still red, now starting at `330%/100%`. What happens if you remove the `font` line altogether? If it works then, then simply specify all the font properties separately, as in `font-family:"Lucida Grande";font-weight:bold;font-size:300%;line-height:100%;`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented it and am still getting the big gradient box in front of everything... hmmm.

Comment: I've looked at a site of mine where I implemented text gradients for `h1`, and I also have a `div` around the header just like you do, and my header also has a background image of its own, similarly to your example. I'm going to bed, so I can't investigate further right now, but feel free to just steal teh codez from me if you wish. A sample HTML page is at http://www.aisee.com/gallery/, and the CSS is at http://www.aisee.com/aisee_new.css. Good night, mate.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "this code makes a big gradient bar appear in front of everything", the gradient is supposed to appear in front of everything, but it's supposed to be transparent and the same colour as your background colour.

Is it possible that you've not exported the PNG correctly? or that the block of colour you've applied the transparency to isn't the correct colour?